# posting nested JSON in Swift with Alamofire

Tags: json, alamofire, swift4

Good day I am currently struggling to post data to my backend I am new to swift development please help

The API expects me to send following structure:

```
{
  "oid": "string",
  "businessKey": "string",
  "refNumber": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "cost": "string",
  "clientOid": "string",
  "vehicleOid": "string",
  "driverOid": "string",
  "from": {
    "oid": "string",
    "businessKey": "string",
    "coordinates": [
      "string"
    ],
    "address": "string"
  },
  "to": {
    "oid": "string",
    "businessKey": "string",
    "coordinates": [
      "string"
    ],
    "address": "string"
  },
  "when": "2018-04-09T10:03:01.156Z",
  "atp": "2018-04-09T10:03:01.156Z",
  "eta": "2018-04-09T10:03:01.156Z",
  "ata": "2018-04-09T10:03:01.156Z",
  "droplets": [
    {
      "oid": "string",
      "businessKey": "string",
      "itemOid": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "notes": "string"
    }
  ],
  "serviceRating": 0,
  "notes": "string"
}
```

This is how is my code:

```
func createDrop(oid: String, token: String){

    let url = getCar.url
    let token = "Bearer " + token
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(url)drops")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue( token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    var parameters: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
        "name": "Thami",
        "notes": "New",
        "cost": "totalPrice",
        "clientOid": "clientOi",
        "vehicleOid": "vehicleOi",
        "driverOid": "driverO",
        "when": "dropTime",
        "atp": "dropTime",
        "eta": "dropTime",
        "ata": "dropTime",
        "from":[
            "coordinates": [
            "-26.002483",
            "28.099503"
            ],
            "address": "his.distanceInfo.getPickUp()",
        ],
        "to":[
            "coordinates": [
            "-26.002483",
            "28.099503"
            ],
            "address": "this.distanceInfo.getDestination()",
        ],
        "droplets":[
            "itemOid": "575ae6bd30bc5d5017477143",
            "notes": "new"
        ]

    ]

    do {
        request.httpBody  = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
        print("serilizing json")
    } catch {
        print("JSON serialization failed:  \(error)")
    }
     print(parameters)
    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {(response) in
         debugPrint(response)
        if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
            print ("pass")
            let dropJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print(dropJSON)
        }else{
            print ("fail gfgdfds")
            let dErrorJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.error!)
            print(dErrorJSON)
        }

    }
}
```

This is the error i am getting:

[Result]: FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

how can I format my object to perform this post

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode the parameters in your request like

`Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)`

Check the docs to get more encoding information 
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#json-encoding